# SQL Grouping with No Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the output. No problem here. Exactly what I want. But I added the DISTINCT ID to remove duplicates and that works in each grouped month.

```
MN   | CNT
====================
1    |  1
10   |  2
11   |  5
12   |  5

SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TRUNC(HDATE)) as MN, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as CNT
    FROM Schema.TRAVEL
        WHERE (ARR = '2' OR ARR = '3')
        AND
        HDATE BETWEEN to_date('2015-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND to_date('2016-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TRUNC(HDATE));
```

But I can still possibly have duplicates that span more than each month. So if I have a record in October and another in November with the same ID - I want to only count this once - that is my issue

So over the course of a year or any time period - an ID only gets counted once...but I still need to maintain the monthly groupings and output...

??

Comment: You need to specify to which month should the `id` count if there are multiple values over more than 1 month.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you want to count each id in the first month where it appears.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TRUNC(HDATE)) as MN, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as CNT
FROM (SELECT id, MIN(HDATE) as HDATE
      FROM Schema.TRAVEL t
      WHERE ARR IN  '2', '3') AND
            HDATE BETWEEN  DATE '2015-10-01' AND DATE '2016-09-30'
      GROUP BY id
     ) t
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TRUNC(HDATE));
```

Note:  If an id appears before `'2015-10-01'`, this will still count the id in the first month it appears after that date.  If you don't want such an `id` counted at all, move the `HDATE` comparison to the outer query.

Comment: Yes - this works great - what I was looking for. thanks. removed the duplicates...

Comment: After thinking about this - I only want an ID counted once - even if its outside the date range - because it will be part of another query...  If there are 4 records with the same ID and different HDATE - I only want to count it once - regardless of whether it falls in the date or not ...